# SQL Rank in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq

I have a SQL query that ranks participants by multiple fields.  I need to convert this to LINQ, which I understand doesn't have a rank function.
Can someone help converting this?

If it helps, here's the what it does.  This query pulls participants from a standings table and ranks them based on the fields that are listed `RANK() OVER (ORDER BY W desc, L asc, RW asc, RL desc, HP desc, TB desc) AS RANK`.  Next I grab only those ranked 1 or 2 `Where q1.RANK in ('1','2')` and see if there are any ties for those two rankings `Having count(q1.ParticipantID) > 1`

```
Select q1.RANK, count(q1.ParticipantID) as 'Count'
From (
        Select Distinct ParticipantID, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY W desc, L asc, RW asc, RL desc, HP desc, TB desc) AS RANK
        From vGroupStandings
        Where CompetitionID = 8
        and GroupNumber = 1
        and EventID = 6
     ) as q1
Where q1.RANK in ('1','2')
Group By q1.RANK
Having count(q1.ParticipantID) > 1
```

**UPDATE**

Here's the data selecting all fields

[image]

Here's an example of what the filtered data in the subquery looks like.  From that set, I look to see if there is more than 1 record ranked at rank 1 or rank 2.

[image]

**RESPONSE**

Thanks for the replies so far, I'll let you know when I can try these out.
Here's another question.  Would it be better to call a stored procedure from a controller instead?  That way I can leave the SQL query as it is.
I have a number of large queries that I'm going to have to run that involve rank.  I wonder if it would be easier than rewriting everything in LINQ.

Comment: I tried using Linqer (which will convert SQL to LINQ for you) and that tells me RANK() conversion is not supported.
I'm pretty new to Linq and this is more complex than I can handle right now.

Comment: @Hogan, the partition part is optional

Comment: ok I see -- it uses the items in the order by to find ties.

Comment: @madvora, did you try the solution from my suggested answer? if so, could you provide some feedback on whether it worked for you?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the responses guys.  I hope this can help others looking for answers in this situation.  I've decided to work with stored procedures rather than clogging up my controllers with millions of lines of complicated linq queries.  While these responses are useful, I can't accept them as the solution I chose.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty ugly, but works for me using this sample class.

```
public class Participant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Score1 { get; set; }
    public int Score2 { get; set; }
    public int ExpectedRank { get; set; }
}
```

On this collection:

```
var participants = new Participant[] {
    new Participant { Id = 1, Score1 = 2, Score2 = 5, ExpectedRank = 6 },
    new Participant { Id = 2, Score1 = 10, Score2 = 8, ExpectedRank = 1 },
    new Participant { Id = 3, Score1 = 7, Score2 = 2, ExpectedRank = 4 },
    new Participant { Id = 4, Score1 = 7, Score2 = 4, ExpectedRank = 3 },
    new Participant { Id = 5, Score1 = 7, Score2 = 2, ExpectedRank = 4 },
    new Participant { Id = 6, Score1 = 7, Score2 = 7, ExpectedRank = 2 },
};
```

By doing the following rather ugly LINQ query:

```
var ranked = participants
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Score1)
    .ThenByDescending(p => p.Score2)
    .Select((p, i) => new { Order = 1 + i, Participant = p })
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.Participant.Score1, p.Participant.Score2 })
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select(p => new {
        Id = p.Participant.Id,
        Rank = g.Min(x => x.Order),
        ExpectedRank = p.Participant.ExpectedRank
    }));

foreach (var p in ranked)
    Console.WriteLine(p);
```

Which produces the following output:

```
{ Id = 2, Rank = 1, ExpectedRank = 1 }
{ Id = 6, Rank = 2, ExpectedRank = 2 }
{ Id = 4, Rank = 3, ExpectedRank = 3 }
{ Id = 3, Rank = 4, ExpectedRank = 4 }
{ Id = 5, Rank = 4, ExpectedRank = 4 }
{ Id = 1, Rank = 6, ExpectedRank = 6 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this... this is pseudo code .... I did not test.

If you gave any example data and expected output then I would do so

```
var inner = datasource
              .OrderByDesc(x => x.W)
              .ThenBy(x => x.L)
               // etc for all orders you need
              .GroupBy(new { W = W, L = L, RW = RW, RL = RL, HP = HP, TB = TB })
              .First(2);

if (inner[0].Count > 1 || inner[1].Count[1] > 1)
{
   Console.Writeline("1 "+inner[0].Count.ToString());
   Console.Writeline("2 "+inner[1].Count.ToString());
}
```

Comment: OK, I added an update so you have a visual sense of what I'm talking about.  The result would just filter down that subquery if there are any ties at rank 1 or 2.  In this case, the query result would be blank (since there are no ties).

Comment: @madvora - got all that.  This is what the code above does too.